# Powershell: delete all the registry keys containing a string

Tags: powershell, registry

I would like to delete all the keys (`1000+`) containing `Python35` from :`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-2\Components`

For instance I would like to delete all the keys similar to that one:

- Keyname: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-2\Components\0027CAECCC428F356B8D845FF8331246`
- Name: `0F617A7B1C879BC47865E0155CDD6722`
- Data: `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\venv\__init__.py`

I tried this.

```
Get-ChildItem -path HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-2\Components\ -Recurse | where { $_.Name -match 'Python35'} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Powershell runs without error,but when I check it in the registry, the keys are still there.

Powershell is run as admin and Admin has the ownership of the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-2\Components` and also full control on that key and its subkeys.

Comment: What output do you get if you omit the Remove-Item, is there any? Check the properties of `Get-ChildItem HKLM:key |Get-Member`

Comment: No output if I omit the `| Remove-Item -Force` part. I didn't find a `Get-ChildItem` in the list cf https://paste.ubuntu.com/24664764/

Comment: Your example key does say `Python36` and not `Python35`. This will not match.

Comment: Sorry, I took the wrong key, there are keys containing  Python35

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
$RE = 'Python35'
$Key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-2\Components'
Get-ChildItem $Key -Rec -EA SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
   $CurrentKey = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PsPath)
   If ($CurrentKey -match $RE){
     $CurrentKey|Remove-Item -Force -Whatif
   }
}
```

If the output looks OK remove the `-WhatIf` paramter from `Remove-Item`

Comment: It's working but I wonder why the code  my question doesn't work.

Comment: I think the Get-ChildItem output from the registry provider isn't directly parseable